# Is it better to book a car rental in advance, or once I'm in Azores?

Tags: car-rentals, portugal, azores

We will be traveling to the Azores, but we haven't decided yet on which islands to combine in our trip of three weeks. How does it work on a multi-island trip to the Azores and renting cars? Should I just rent on arrival on each island or is there a multi-island formula?

Comment: What I can tell you from my experience with rental cars, is that there is a huge issue with taking cars on ferries. The insurance companies often do not allow this. So while a rental website might allow you to rent a car on one island and return it on another, once you get to pickup your car, they might refuse it. Got that issue in NZ...

Comment: I am not sure there are car ferries in the azores. So I am afraid I would need to rent a different car on each island

Comment: After traveling to the Azores "unprepared". The answer seems that you better come prepared. We had hard times getting rentals. To enjoy the Azores one needs a car. So better book in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably start with the [Azores.com](http://www.azores.com) which has a lot of useful information including [car rental information](http://www.azores.com/car) and [ferry information](http://www.azores.com/ferry).

The issue with most of these islands is that they are small.  I've been to Terceira and was able to drive around the perimeter of the entire island in less then an hour but there are places that you would want to visit but has no organized bus tours to get to.

As far as car rental is concerned I would rent on each of the Islands separately since the ferry that can carry a car from one island to another [only runs once a week](http://www.angra2000.com/ferries/downloads/atlanticoline/horarios.pdf).  The passenger ferry only run by [Transmacor](http://www.angra2000.com/ferries/downloads/atlanticoline/horarios.pdf) has daily service between the islands making choice a simple one.